# How is stratifying by X in proportional hazards model different from adjusting for X?

Tags: cox-model

I'm familiar with stratification vs adjustment in linear regression. I'm wondering if stratification vs adjustment in CPH is conceptually similar? The stratification variable I have question about is calendar time. Context is modelling the survival of AMKL, a leukemia subtype. In the last few decades, The identification of AMKL changed because of advancements in diagnostic tests, and new treatment of AMKL came out, so survival rate increased. I wish to account for these changes over time but am not sure whether to stratify the CPH by decades (1950-59, 1960-69, 1970-79, etc.) or include subject's birthyear as a covariate. Thank you!